# How to create email key in Realtime Database using FirebaseDatabase.Net

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms

I want to create **user email keys** instead of the auto-generated keys. The reason why i want to do this, is to be able to query for that particular email and get that user data instead of getting all users from the "Users" child data which is not convenient, especially if the amount of users will grow.

I'am using [FirebaseDatabase.Net](https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-database-dotnet) which is available as a nuget. It is a wrapper on top of Firebase Realtime Database REST API.

A new user gets added into the realtime database with auto-generated keys as shown below. If those keys were the user emails instead, maybe i can query the user email and get that particular email child data, like the code below:

```
         await firebase
              .Child("Users")
              .Child("user1@email.com")
              .OnceSingleAsync<User>());
```

[image]

Im using the codes from a sample examples. The functions below are to get all users, add new use and to get a user.

```
        public FirebaseClient firebase = new FirebaseClient("firebaseurl");

        public async Task<List<User>> GetAllUsers()
        {
            return (await firebase
                  .Child("Users")
                  .OnceAsync<User>()).Select(item => new User
                  {
                      Firstname = item.Object.Firstname,
                      Lastname = item.Object.Lastname,
                      Username = item.Object.Username,
                      Email = item.Object.Email,
                      Password = item.Object.Password,
                  }).ToList();
        }

        public async Task<User> GetUser(string email)
        {
            var AllUsers = await GetAllUsers();
            await firebase
              .Child("Users")
              .OnceAsync<User>();
            return AllUsers.Where(a => a.Email == email).FirstOrDefault();
        }

        public async Task<bool> AddUser(User newUser)
        {
            try
            {
                await firebase
                  .Child("Users")
                  .PostAsync(newUser);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error:{e}");
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Please guide me into creating email keys instead of the auto-generated keys so that i can request a particular user data using an email key instead of getting all users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eagerly waited for an answer, refreshing the page so many times. Luckily i found a way to do it.

**To create an email key**, first replace any **characters** like **". $ # [ ]"** in your email string because Firebase does not support them. Or **another way** is to convert the string to byte array then to base64. The good thing is that base64 string alphabet does not have those characters, so it is safe to use it.

[image: Base64 Alphabet]

Then in the AddUser function, put the base64 email key child under the main child "User2". The main child can be of any name, im going to change it after this. The "PutAsync" will put the new user data inside that email child.

Please take note, the "User" as seen in the AddUser function parameter, is a class i defined that has user properties like firstname, lastname, email, country, phone and so on.

```
public async Task<bool> AddUser(User newUser)
        {
            try
            {
                string userEmail = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(newUser.Email));

                await firebase
                  .Child("User2")
                  .Child(userEmail)
                  .PutAsync(newUser);

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error:{e}");
                return false;
            }
        }
```

And it worked! In the image below, the old "Users" child had auto-generated keys, but the new "User2" child had a base64 email key. Don't worry, it can be easily obtained in the GetUser function.

The email "**ibrahim155255@gmail.com**" becomes "**aWJyYWhpbTE1NTI1NUBnbWFpbC5jb20=**" when converted to base64.

[image]

In the GetUser function, the email is converted to base64 the same way it was done in the AddUser function. If the base64 email key child is present inside the "User2" child, the user data is returned.

```
public async Task<User> GetUser(string email)
        {
            try
            {
                string userEmail = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(email));

                return (await firebase
                  .Child("User2")
                  .Child(userEmail)
                  .OnceSingleAsync<User>());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error:{e}");
                return null;
            }
        }
```

I hope this answer is useful. If it helped you, please thumbs up the answer, i will truly appreciate.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, please do not forget to mark it answer after three days.

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT Good to hear that. Thank you for letting me know about marking it answered, i didn't know, now i know.